# How to insert a record into a table with a column declared with the SERIAL function

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, auto-increment, postgresql-serial

My database is using PostgreSQL. One table is using the `serial` auto-increment macro. If I want to insert a record into the table, do I still need to specify that value, or it is be automatically assigned for me?

```
CREATE TABLE dataset
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    age integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text
    CONSTRAINT dataset_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Using the `DEFAULT` keyword or by omitting the column from the `INSERT` list:

```
INSERT INTO dataset (id, age, name, description)
VALUES (DEFAULT, 42, 'fred', 'desc');

INSERT INTO dataset (age, name, description)
VALUES (42, 'fred', 'desc');
```

Comment: both of these style doesn't work for me. I also tried with Insert into table_name values()

Comment: @MuhammadNouman Then you're getting something wrong or what you're using isn't PostgreSQL. Please post a new question. Put a link in it pointing to this one for context if you like.

Comment: thank you for `DEFAULT` keyword prompt

Answer (score 6):

If you create a table with a serial column then if you omit the serial column when you insert data into the table PostgreSQL will use the sequence automatically and will keep the order.

Example:

```
skytf=> create table test_2 (id serial,name varchar(32));
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "test_2_id_seq" for serial column "test_2.id"
CREATE TABLE

skytf=> insert into test_2 (name) values ('a');
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into test_2 (name) values ('b');
INSERT 0 1
skytf=> insert into test_2 (name) values ('c');
INSERT 0 1

skytf=> select * From test_2;
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | a
  2 | b
  3 | c
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 5):

These query work for me:

```
insert into <table_name> (all columns without id serial)
select (all columns without id serial)
 FROM <source> Where <anything>;
```

Comment: Is `all columns without id serial` a special keyword?

Comment: @Snozzlebert no this was just the poster's shorthand. Basically means that in the column list you include any column that is not of type serial, and in the select list the same.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you create **"person" table** with **"id"** of **serial** and **"name"**  as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Then, you can use `DEFAULT` for **"id"** of **serial** and insert rows without **column(field) names** as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO person VALUES (DEFAULT, 'John'), (DEFAULT, 'Tom');
```

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM person;
 id | name
----+------
  1 | John
  2 | Tom
```

Answer (score 2):

Inserting multiple rows wasn't working for me in this scenario:

```
create table test (
  id bigint primary key default gen_id(),
  msg text not null
)

insert into test (msg)
select gs
from generate_series(1,10) gs;
```

because I had mistakenly marked my gen_id function IMMUTABLE.

The insert query was being optimized to only call that function once rather than 10 times. Oops...